# Сохранение в .plist

Tags: ipad, xcode, objective-c, iphone

Добрый день. У меня есть задачка и я не могу с ней справиться. Мне нужно сохранять данные в плист файл.

У меня есть текстовое поле6 куда польхователь вводит текст, мне надо что б при каждом нажатии на save у него заносилось это в .plist file дабы потом он мог это посмотреть.

textForSave - вот тут нахожиться текст который ввели

```
- (IBAction)saveResult:(id)sender {

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //1
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //2
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data.plist"]; //3

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: path]) //4
    {
        NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"]; //5

        [fileManager copyItemAtPath:bundle toPath: path error:&error]; //6
    }
}
```

А это "мой" код по добавлению в плист. Вроде он кашерный и должен работать. Вот только куда мне прописать мой  textForSave что б он его добавил в plist ???

Comment: То есть я правильно понимаю: вы написали код, который правильно сохраняет текст в файл, и вы не можете подставить в него свой текст?

Comment: Я пока не дорос до уровня что б писать такой код, Я только учусь =))) я нашел туториал... Сделал все как там описывалось... 

Но по логике он не указывает на моей файл к котором текст, а значит и не сохраняет его=)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С `plist'ами` проще всего работать через методы `NSMutableDictionary + (id)dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:(NSString *)path` и - `(BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag` (или аналогичные у массива, зависит от структуры `plist'a`), ну а далее работаете как с обычным словарем\массивом.

[Reading and Writing Property-List Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/ReadWritePlistData/ReadWritePlistData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH8-SW1).

Comment: Можете подсказать какой-то урок наглядный ???

Comment: Боюсь, что нет. По идее, вам нужно следующее - берете вашу переменную `NSString *bundle` (в порядке совета - имя замените, это все-таки не бандл приложения), потом пишете что-то типа `NSMutableDictionary *dict=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:bundle];` и получаете свой плист, загруженный в словарь, далее вставляете свой текст`[dict setObject: textForSave forKey:@"YorKeyName"];` и сохраняете `[dict writeToFile:path atomically:YES];`, если текст нужно вставить куда-то глубже в иерархию плиста, нужна вытащить этот пункт иерархии с помощью objectForKey: и уже с ним работать ...

Comment: А потом поместить этот пункт назад и сохранить (в комменте символы закончились :) )